# How to apply different DataTemplate to a Listview

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

In my UWP App, I have a scenario in which there are multiple pages, which constains ListView to display data, and each page have there own DataTemplate base on the content to display, now the styling/colors of ListView and DataTemplate on each page is same, so the problem is that whenever I need to change any style inside DataTemplate, like setting border I need to go on each page to do that, so How can I make a common UI for data template but with different data to display and than assign that to ListView, I tried to create UserControl with a listview but I don't know How can I pass Datatemplate to that listview.

Here's what I tried at first level:

Create User control and a Dependency Property for DataTemplate:
UserControl CS File:

```
  public DataTemplate DisplayItemTemplate
    {
        get { return (DataTemplate)GetValue(DisplayItemTemplateProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DisplayItemTemplateProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DisplayItemTemplateProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("DisplayItemTemplate", typeof(DataTemplate), typeof(ListViewControl), new PropertyMetadata(null));
```

UserControl  Xaml File:

```
 <ListView x:Name="DisplayListView"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      ItemTemplate="{Binding DisplayItemTemplate, Mode=OneWay}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResourceListViewItemExpandedStyle}"
                      ItemClick="DisplayListView_ItemClick">
```

PeoplePage, where I am using this UserControl:

```
  <controls:ListViewControl x:Name="MyListView"
                              Grid.Row="1"
                              DisplayItemTemplate="{StaticResource MyListDataTemplate}" />
```

The issue is that MyListDataTemplate is not getting set as a DataTemplate in DisplayListView.

Comment: define datatemplate in app.xaml as application Resources

Comment: You have to use Commands or Behaviours for event handlers in that case,since you cant put event handlers in app.xaml.cs

Comment: How are you using Usercontrol? please post complete code

Comment: I already mentioned that in "UserControl Caller" section.

Comment: Sorry,I dint get it,Can you elaborate?

Comment: check for section "UserControl Caller:" in my post, that is how I am using/calling UserControl.

Comment: Yes i got that. I asked where exactly did you call that? I mean where hav been added that code

Comment: I have another page called PeoplePage and inside that have a Grid section which contains this usercontrol.

Comment: In same page where ListView is there?

Comment: No. Have Usercontrol named ListViewUserControl which .cs and .xaml file I have mentioned in my post, and now I am using that control in PeoplePage.

Comment: Ok. Now i understood. Sorry for the confusion. You have to mention user control name as ElementName in binding,Check the answer,Let me know if you have any problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<UserControl x:Name="userControl"> 
...
<ListView x:Name="DisplayListView"
                      IsItemClickEnabled="True"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                      ItemTemplate="{Binding DisplayItemTemplate,ElementName=userControl,Mode=OneWay}"
                      ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResourceListViewItemExpandedStyle}"
                      ItemClick="DisplayListView_ItemClick">
...
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Thnx. That Works! What's the magic behind it? Why I need to specify ElementName?

Comment: Because DisplayItemTemplate is a custom dependency property. ListView wont be knowing where does it come from(source) unless you mention

Comment: Thanks for the info.